# Mapping a Java property to several xml attributes using JAXB and MOXy

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have a simple class CustomQuoteRequest:

```
public class CustomQuoteRequest {

  private String requestId;

  private String currencyPairCode;

  public String getRequestId() {
    return requestId;
  }

  public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
    this.requestId = requestId;
  }

  public String getCurrencyPairCode() {
    return currencyPairCode;
  }

  public void setCurrencyPairCode(String currencyPairCode) {
    this.currencyPairCode = currencyPairCode;
  }
}
```

I would like to map currencyPairCode to two different attributes in the xml. This is the MOXy mapping file I am using:

```
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_oxm_2_1.xsd"
    >
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="com.anz.fxeasy.domain.model.quote.CustomQuoteRequest"  xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
            <xml-root-element name="FIXML"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="requestId" xml-path="QuotReq/@ReqId"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="currencyPairCode" xml-path="QuotReq/QuoteReq/Instrmt/@Sym"></xml-element>
                <xml-element java-attribute="currencyPairCode" xml-path="QuotReq/QuoteReq/Leg/Leg/@Sym"></xml-element>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
```

However the second xml-element seems to override the previous one. Any ideas?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EclipseLink MOXy 2.1.X**

In EclipseLink 2.1.X you can use an XML Customizer to accomplish this.  Your external metadata would look like the following:

```
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_oxm_2_1.xsd"
    >
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="forum78.CustomQuoteRequest"  xml-accessor-type="FIELD" xml-customizer="customizer.CustomQuoteRequestCustomizer">
            <xml-root-element name="FIXML"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="requestId" xml-path="QuotReq/@ReqId"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="currencyPairCode" xml-path="QuotReq/QuoteReq/Instrmt/@Sym"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

In the customizer we'll add a second mapping for the currencyCodePair property.  We will need to indicate that this mapping is write only.  The implementation of the XML customizer would look like the following:

```
package customizer;

import org.eclipse.persistence.config.DescriptorCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping;

public class CustomQuoteRequestCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
        XMLDirectMapping  currencyPairCodeLegMapping = new XMLDirectMapping();
        currencyPairCodeLegMapping.setAttributeName("currencyPairCode");
        currencyPairCodeLegMapping.setXPath("QuotReq/QuoteReq/Leg/Leg/@Sym");
        currencyPairCodeLegMapping.setIsWriteOnly(true);
        descriptor.addMapping(currencyPairCodeLegMapping);

    }

}
```

**EclipseLink MOXy 2.2**

In the upcoming EclipseLink 2.2 release you will be able to do this using just the externalized metadata:

```
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_oxm_2_1.xsd"
    >
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="forum78.CustomQuoteRequest"  xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
            <xml-root-element name="FIXML"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="requestId" xml-path="QuotReq/@ReqId"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="currencyPairCode" xml-path="QuotReq/QuoteReq/Instrmt/@Sym"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="currencyPairCode" xml-path="QuotReq/QuoteReq/Leg/Leg/@Sym" write-only="true"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

The following bug can be used to track this support:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/328135